# Notation for space-time function

Tags: spacetime, vectors, notation

I have a quantity which depends on time and space. I'm using the following notation throughout my paper

$$f(x,y,z,t)= \alpha\nabla^2f +...$$

While the right-hand side is compact by virtue of Laplacian, Divergence and gradient operators, the left-hand size does not seem nice. I need to refer to $f(x,y,z,t)$ in the writing very often and emphasize the time and space dependency distinctly but not $x$,$y$ or $z$ specifically. What's an appropriate notation for such cases? Something like $f(s,t)$ where $s=<x,y,z>$ is the space vector does look nice either as it adds unnecessary definition and confusion, or I have to do it this way? **$f$ is stress field.**

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [questions asking for the standard (or appropriate) notation for something are off-topic](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4063/50583).

Answer (score 2):

Often people use bold for a vector such as $\boldsymbol{x} $ or $\boldsymbol{r} $, or you could use some accented variable such as $\hat{x} $ though this would be considered unusual. Then you just add an inline definition after the first use, eg "where $\boldsymbol{x} =(x, y, z) $" . Typically it's a bad idea to use angle brackets, these are reserved for specific situations.